# Would you like to be a moderator on Tor Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, moderators

We're looking for another moderator, as [Samuel](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/15/samuel-walker) has found himself quite busy in the real world, and needs to return to an ordinary tor citizen for the foreseeable future.

To that, we're looking to find someone just as friendly and as helpful as him, who has a bit of time to give to leading this community and helping to keep things clean and running smoothly.

The job entails the following responsibilities:

- Tend to flags as they're raised, which is relatively infrequent. You'll mostly be called upon to check out a closed question which was closed without a comment, and see if you can be of any help to the person asking. There's occasional spam, and the occasional 'thanks' or 'me too!' answer to dispose of.
- Help the community with larger scale tag operations, using your super powers that come with your shiny new diamond
- Be a liaison between us (the community team) and the Tor SE community. You'll have our ear,  tell us what we can do to help this community continue to grow and thrive
- Intervene in *exceedingly* rare disputes between users. You won't see a lot of that here.
- Check in on the Tor meta site, to see if new users need guidance, or a concern was raised that might need your attention.

You'll of course have access to special tools that assist you in doing your job, and you'll have access to a special chat room where you can find help from moderators on all of our other sites.

The ideal candidate should:

- Have at least a bit of rep. You don't have to be a high-rep user, we just need to make sure you have enough knowledge of the topic in order to judge the quality of any given post.
- Have a history of being patient, fair and friendly in your interations
- Have read and understand our [theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- Want the job, and have a few hours per week on average to give to the site

We're respectful of your time, if you need to take a vacation, take a few weeks off - whatever might come up - that's fine, just let us know as much in advance as possible so we can make sure the site is covered.

Interested? Great! Nominate yourself by posting an answer to this question, just link to your profile on the main site and let us know about directions you'd like to see the site go, any problems you see the site having, or just your philosophy on moderation in general. I hope to have someone appointed within the next 7 - 10 days, so please don't hesitate to throw your hat in if you're interested!

Good luck to all of you.

***Update***

Stig has stepped up and accepted his nomination, please join me and welcoming him as your new moderator on his first day in his new role:

[image: profile for Stig Atle Steffensen at Tor Stack Exchange, Q&A for researchers, developers, and users of Tor]

He's remarked that he's excited to be able to give more back to the Tor community at-large, and we're pleased to have him in a position where he can do just that.

Thank you to everyone that showed interest, all of you would have done a fine job, there's just a limited number of positions to fill. Once the site graduates at some point in the future, moderator elections will be scheduled, and I encourage everyone that showed interest here to nominate themselves then.

Thanks again, everyone!

Comment: Thanks for helping out Stig; I really appreciate you stepping up while other Sam and I were away! This really shows that the community is still thriving.

Answer (score 3):

I would be interested. Not sure how much time I'd actually be able to put into it unless I actually become a moderator.

I agree with the theory of moderation here (thought that should be said)

http://stackexchange.com/users/3381620/puser

Comment: It doesn't take much more than what you normally give the site just by using it. The difference being there might be a flag or two to attend to, or maybe a question to answer on Tor Meta.

Comment: yeah, I'd imagine it wouldn't be that much, as tor has relatively low traffic compared to other stackexchanges

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested becoming a moderator. I've necessary skills and knowledge. My moderation experience on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55075/kenorb?tab=activity&sort=reviews) and [superuser](https://superuser.com/users/87805/kenorb?tab=activity&sort=reviews) would be an asset.

Answer (score 2):

If the position is still open, I would like to apply. I have good experience with Tor and I usually visit Tor Stack Exchange everyday.

http://stackexchange.com/users/4153902/umut-seven

Answer (score 2):

I would volunteer if you need any more help.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I do enjoy helping people, and I do frequent everything that has to do with Tor and other such networks. And I really like the Tor stack exchange site.
And I do answer everything I can when it shows up.

I'm not a crypto expert coder, but I do know my way around most of Tor and other such tools, since I've been using them for many years on both windows and linux, as servers and clients.